# How to install libxml2 for python when using pyenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, homebrew, libxml2

Here are the details of my python install:

- OS X 10.9
- homebrew used to install pyenv (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)
- python was installed  via `pyenv install 2.7.6`
- custom `virtualenv` just for this project

Given the above python install, how would someone set up libxml2?

So far, I've tried `brew install libxml2`, hacking the recipe to have --with-python. That seems to compile, but then python starts having SegFaults when I try to use libxml2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us the **full** error trackback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
brew install libxml2 --with-python
```

Some files were installed into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libxml2*`. I copied them to my virtualenv's site-packages and voila things worked!

Symlinking might be something better to try.

Answer (score 2):

It may possibly be related to packages being compiled against old libxml2. You can check libxml2 origin with [`gdb`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543521), run `gdb python` and execute command that lead to SegFault.

One option why it is happening is that brew installed libxml2 to local folder, say `/usr/local`, and your packages are compiled against libraries shipped with OS (usually old and buggy on OSX, not sure  for Mavericks) from `/usr/lib` are being used.